# Modeling Votes on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to create a votable entity on GAE's datastore.  I would like to show the user a control to vote for this entity or an icon indicating that they have already voted for it; ie, I'm asking "has a user voted on this entity?"  Lets say that we have a Question entity that a user may up-vote.  Here is what I'm thinking of doing:

1. Query for my Question entities.  These questions already have a precalculated ranking on which I will sort.
2. Use a relation index entity that is a child of the Question entity.  Query for all Questions using the same filters as #1 where my user is a member of this relation index entity.
3. Merge the results of #2 into #1 by setting a hasVoted property to true for each found set member.

This is the cleanest way I could think of doing it but it still requires two queries.  I didn't to create duplicate Question entities for each user to own because it would cause too much data duplication.  Is this solution a good way to handle what is effectively a join between a m2m relationship between Votes and Questions or am I thinking too relationally?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a relation index, just have a child entity for each user that's voted on the question. Make the key_name of the child entity the ID of the user. Then, to determine if a user y has voted on a question with ID x, simply fetch the key (Question:x/Vote:y). You can batch this to fetch multiple entities for multiple questions or users, too.

Comment: Why did you suggest to keep the child entities on the question side, and not the user side? If a question is popular, wouldn't it pass the maximum write limit of the question entity group? Any downsides of keeping the votes on the user side?

Comment: @ali Having votes be child entities of the question allows you to do a single atomic fetch for all votes to get an accurate count.

Comment: Shouldn't the votes count be stored as a property of the question entity?

Comment: Another problem: Wouldn't keeping votes as children of question entity make it impossible to query for all votes of a user across all questions? (like what stackoverflow does)

Comment: @ali No, you can do non-ancestor queries for child entities just the same as you can for root entities. And, if that were true, then having votes under the user would make it impossible to actually count votes on a question. :)

Comment: Sure, we can have a non-ancestor query _if_ we add an indexed user id field to vote child entity. But we already have user id as the key_name of vote. How is it possible to write a non-ancestor query filtered by key_name of the child entity?

Comment: It's not - you need to add it as a field, as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look to [Overheard](http://just-overheard-it.appspot.com/) Google App Engine sample application.

> Our basic model will be to have
>   Quotes, which contain a string for the
>   quotation, and Votes, which contain
>   the user name and vote for a
>   particular user.

There's a [Google article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/overheard.html) about it and [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/overheard/models.py) you can find the sources.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the second query, you could store *all* of the questions a user has voted on in a single entity.  This entity could be part of the User model, or exist in a one-to-one relationship with User entities.

You could then load this information as needed (and store it to memcache to avoid datastore loads) so that you can quickly check if a user has already voted on a question (without doing a second query most of the time).

If a user may vote on a really large number of questions, then you may have to extend this idea.  Here is an *outline* (not functionally complete) of how you might go about the simple scheme:

```
class UserVotes(db.Model):
    # key = key_name or ID of the corresponding user entity

    # if all of your question entities have IDs, then voted_on can be a list of 
    # integers; otherwise it can be a list of strings (key_name values)
    voted_on = db.ListProperty(int, indexed=False)  

# in your request handler ...
questions = ...
voted_on = memcache.get('voted-on:%s' % user_id)
if voted_on is None:
    voted_on = UserVotes.get_by_id(user_id)  # should do get_or_insert() instead
    memcache.set(...)
for q in questions:
    q.has_voted = q.key().id() in voted_on
```

Comment: I would replace `if not voted_on:` with `if voted_on is None:` because if `voted_on=[]` than `if not coted_on:` is True.

Comment: @David- wouldn't it be simpler to create a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` on User called user_votes, which contains the keys of user-voted questions?

Comment: @Yarin That would work too, though I tend to avoid completely `db.Key` so that any dereferencing of the key (and loading of the corresponding entity from the db [not cheap!]) is an explicit decision.